# Request Header in Angular 5.2

Tags: angular, post, http-headers, angular5

I am trying to make post request. the SessionConfirmationNumber is getting removed. Everything else is fine. I can see it's value in console log

```
console.log('the Session Number', options.headers.sessionConfirmationNumber) //works can see the value e.g.: 23524545245

return this.http
    .post(environment.domain + url, body,  { headers: new HttpHeaders({
      '_dynSessConf': options.headers.sessionConfirmationNumber,
      'Authorization_Test': 'TestValue',
      'ClientBrowserId': options.headers.clientbrowseruid,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })})
    .catch(this.config.handleError)
    .map((responseData: any) => {
      console.log('Response Data ', responseData)          
    })
```

when I check the network tab it literally removes _dynSessConf. 
I tried hardcoding value '_dynSessConf' :'test-val'  and it works. Just when it has the value it doesnt work.
It is very frustrating.

I tried  creating httpHeader and appending the values

```
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers = headers.append('Authorization_Test', 'TestValue');
        headers = headers.append('DynSess', options.headers.sessionConfirmationNumber);

    return this.http
    .post(environment.domain + url, body,  { headers: headers})
```

again i can see the values in console under lazyUpdate. But it complains about

[image]

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): profileService.handleProfile error TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to Cast the number to a String before sending it as a parameter.

```
const dynNum = String(options.headers._dynSessConf)
this.http
    .post(environment.domain + url, body,  { headers: new HttpHeaders({
      '_dynSessConf': dynNum,
      'Authorization_Test': 'TestValue',
      'ClientBrowserId': 'options.headers.clientbrowseruid',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })})
```